# Why Theme Of BottomSheetDialog Not Working if Expanded?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

My Theme Resource not working when BottomSheetDialog is Expanded state?

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
}
```

> When calling on My Activity, Theme resources is not working?

```
val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this,
    R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_RoundShapeBottomSheetDialog)
```

When Expanded mode, background bottomsheet back to default, Why this?

Answer (score 0):

Customize the BottomSheetDialog Background,you can create a custom style for the BottomSheetDialog that modifies the default background.

```html
 <!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:background">@color/your_custom_background_color</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogCornerRadius">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Then apply this theme when creating your BottomSheetDialog:

```
val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme);
```

Comment: Already create custom xml style, but not working when expanded bottomsheet. Why?